# What is the regular expression for word boundaries?

Tags: regex, grep

Some background, I found almost what I am looking for in:
Regular expression Anchors examples

## Match beginning of line

```
$ grep '^L' file

       **L**ine one
```

## Match end of the line

```
      $  grep 'e$' file

          Line on**e**
```

Here my question is how to match beginning of word and end of word.
For example i want to match like this:

Match beginning of each word: **L**ine **o**ne
Match end of the each word: Lin**e** on**e**

Could you please some one help on this?

Thanks

Comment: You could use `or` which is represented in `|`, something like this: `grpe '^L|e$' file`

Comment: from man page for GNU grep which has a section for REGULAR EXPRESSIONS `The symbols \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.  The  symbol  \b
       matches  the empty string at the edge of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided it's not at the edge
       of a word.`

Answer (score 6):

#### End of word

```
grep "e\>" file
```

i.e. ends with lower case e

#### Beginning of word

```
grep "\<L" file
```

i.e. begins with upper case L

Tested with GNU grep

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `\b` anchor which does the following.

> Matches a word boundary position such as whitespace, punctuation, or the start/end of the string. This matches a position, not a character.

```
\b\w // beginning character
\w\b // end character
```

http://regexr.com/3fjot